# Spring Secuirty SAML2 Core - Add a key for an Identity Provider created on runtime

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml, saml-2.0, spring-security-saml2

Currently I am editing existing implementation of SAML support on my project using Spring Security.
I have multiple IdentityProviders, for which I store data in the database.
Using my app UI I can add new IdentityProviders on runtime, which will be added to CachingMetadataManager. After that, refreshMetadata is called.
However I have JKSKeyManager, which is loaded on app startup and loads a single JKS keystore which is used for all metadatas for all IdentityProviders.
I want a user to be able to upload (or paste) a private key using my app UI during IdentityProvider creation on runtime, so that, different key can be used for different IdentityProvider, but I don't know how. There's no difference for me if I store the keys in JKS file or somewhere else.
There's no spring boot and I am afraid there is no ability to upgrade the library versions/migrate to other libraries.

The key manager injection looks like this:

```
@Bean
  public KeyManager keyManager() {
    DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
    Resource storeFile = loader
        .getResource(environment.getProperty("server.ssl.key-store"));
    Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<>();
    passwords.put(environment.getProperty("server.ssl.key-alias"), environment.getProperty("server.ssl.key-store-password"));
    String defaultKey = "spring";
    return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, environment.getProperty("server.ssl.key-store-password"), passwords, defaultKey);
  }
```

SAML extension used is spring-security-saml2-core (1.0.3.RELEASE) from org.springframework.security.extensions.
And Spring Security vesion is 3.2.9.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `JKSKeyManager` computes all the available keys at construction time, a custom implementation of `KeyManager` would likely be best.

Something like the following, for example:

```
public DynamicJKSKeyManager extends JKSKeyManager {
    private final KeyStore keyStore;

    public KeyStoreKeyManager(KeyStore keyStore, Map<String, String> passwords, String defaultKey) {
        super(keyStore, passwords, defaultKey);
        this.keyStore = keyStore;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getAvailableCredentials() {
        try {
            Set<String> availableKeys = new HashSet<String>();
            Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();
            while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
                availableKeys.add(aliases.nextElement());
            }
            return availableKeys;
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load aliases from keyStore", e);
        }
    }
}
```

would change the `getAvailableCredentials` method to read the `KeyStore` aliases on each invocation.

Then, when you need to add a key to the `KeyStore`, you can use the `KeyStore` API to do it.

Of course, as you mentioned, you don't have to use `KeyStore`. Wherever you store your keys, you can implement your own `KeyManager` and use OpenSAML's `CollectionCredentialResolver` instead of `KeyStoreCredentialResolver`.